# In ASP, what is the best way to save request variables to a frame <frame src="SomeOther.asp"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic, frames

I have a main page with a frame with its attribute src set to equal "SomeOther.asp".

Since I have some rather large request variables, I want to save my request variables from my current page into my SomeOther.asp frame.  Is there a way to transfer my request variables to my frame's page? The reason is b/c in my SomeOther.asp   I can't really use query string for all variables b/c one is a bunch of 1,2,3,4,5,..... 4000 more of them which represents IDs, and I'd rather not use cookies, but I can use request object, or perhaps a session variable.

If I can't use request attributes I am planning on using a session variable and just transferring the name of this variable in a query string ie... `<frame src="SomeOther.asp?mysess=uniquesessionname ...`

Here is my workflow page1 form loaded, submit button hit, from data submitted to post to page2. Page2 automatically calls page3 with query string data. Page3 has the frame on it. I can access the request input items from page1 on page3, but not on page3's frame. This is what I'm trying to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by post method on same page as src of Ifram.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="v.asp" method="post">
    <iframe src="v.asp"></iframe>
    <input type="text"  name="txt1" value="123" />
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is my workflow page1 form loaded, submit button hit,  from data submitted to post to page2.  Page2 automatically calls page3 with query string data.  Page3 has the frame on it.  I can access the request input items from page1 on page3, but not on page3's frame.  This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi RetroCoder, You can achive like this. on page load of page 2 you can get all the values from page 1 and stored in any hidden fields. then post page2 to page3 so you can get page1 data via page 2 on page3

Comment: I'm checking this right now, but so far its going grand, thanks for the help!

Comment: This is really great , Please let me know if you need any help from my side.

Comment: How do I automatically submit in jQuery or javascript?  I think I can get this to work.

Comment: I think I can get this form submit thing to work by throwing jQuery at it. $("form#forceSubmitFormOnLoad").submit();

Comment: Got it to work... I did not add the asp page, so you'll see the error.  Thanks a lot! http://jsfiddle.net/mnoon/xvuEw/

Comment: One little side note: to actually get the value I had to use javascript or jQuery in the v.asp page to retrieve the input. i.e.:  alert(window.parent.document.getElementById("txt1").getAttribute("value").valueOf());

Comment: Finally this is used inside of v.asp: $("#V_id1").text(window.parent.document.getElementsByName("txt1").getAttribute("value").valueOf());

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your querystring to the iframe using JavaScript:

```
document.frames[0].src="SomeOther.asp?" + document.location.pathname
```

Comment: The request("name") is not a query string. This is an asp attribute which is used in a post operation. I want to transfer my request object to my frame. I don't want to transfer my query strings to my frame.

Comment: I think I can use a javascript window.parent.form but not sure how to get the variable name.  Is is it form("varname")?  b/c I want to get the form.request("varname") from the parent.

Comment: I believe you want the "action" property of the form. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to clarify what you mean by request variables. Variables in query strings would generally be considered request variables but you say you can't use querystring... Do you mean you want to do them like form submission? And where are these variables coming from? Are they calculated in your asp page or are they external parameters passed to your parent page somehow?

You can set the target for a form submission to be an iframe in which case the response from the form will be displayed in the frame.

You can as others have suggested put the variables on the querystring but you suggest that might get too long.

If they are starting off on the server then storing them on the server is sensible. If in session you can either store each of the variables in an equivalent session variable. This will cause problems if the user has multiple copies of the page open.

You can do as you suggest and store all the variables under a single unique session key and then pass that as the single querystring parameter.

Lastly you could store the state into a persistent medium such as a database and use the id of that in your frame querystring to retrieve it. This may be better than storing in session depending on the size of what you are storing, volume of traffic, etc. Generally it can be a very bad idea to store anything too large in session due to the amount of memory you may start eating up if you aren't careful.

Without more details it is hard to say what will be best for your scenario but hopefully the above should give you some ideas on where you can go with it.

Comment: I mean variables that are tranfered during a POST html form submit.

Comment: I think the correct name is an Attribute or a Request Attribute.  I want to transfer the the form.request from the main document to the frame.  <body><frame src="aframewithinthebody.asp" width etc..>

Answer (score 1):

Is it absolutely necessary that you use a frame? If it's just to display a menu or special area only visible to a logged in user, you should really consider using CSS to create the "frame" effect then you won't need to pass your request variables to your frame or have to necessarily mess around with sessions just to pass information from one to the other.

Here are some examples:
http://fu2k.org/alex/css/frames/scalablefixed
http://www.webpelican.com/web-tutorials/css-frames-tutorial/

If the frame is necessary then I'd suggest going with sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep the structure this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate with the submited data within an iframe, why not use "target" attribute of the form tag to point to the iframe?

```
<form action="ProcessPage.asp" target="iframeName">
     ....all your inputs...
</form>
<iframe name="iframeName"></iframe>
```

Comment: Wow, I hadn't thought of that either.  Let me try that as well.  I think you and Jinesh Jain must be very good at this stuff.

Comment: I want to give both you an Jinesh equal points, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it is possible to bind query string variables inside of `frame` elements:

```
<frame src="SomeOther.asp?someid=5&mode=2"/>
```

AFAIK, HTML treats all URLs the same and so frames can contain the same query string data as normal Page URLs have. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to send a large amount of data and I've already tried this.  But I was thinking of using a unique session id and putting that in the query string.  I don't want to use a session variable if I can help it.  I'd rather send the data some other way from the parent window to the iframe.